# Cannot add JPA entity to DB

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I'm having problems persisting an entity:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestExampleBean {

    private TestEntity r;  // simple table: ID, NAME (Auto generated from sql table so I think the class code is ok!)

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Test-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void save() {
        // Print statements will execute here if added so this methods does run

        r = new TestEntity();
        r.setName("TESTER");

        em.persist(r);
    }

}
```

The save method of this EJB is called from a JSF managed bean. The entity has ID and NAME(VARCHAR) attributes.

I cannot get anything to persist in the DB... but no errors are showing on glassfish server.

Comment: suppose you add `em.flush();` at the end and see for exceptions.

Comment: No exceptions..

Comment: did you try with adding `@Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)` to the `save()`

Comment: Why not just look in the JPA provider log for what is happening?!

Comment: isn't there any missing dependency (related entity should be exist)?